# Uso correcto de docstring en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, docstrings

soy desarrollador de Python más o menos avanzado, sin embargo nunca habia utilizado *docstring*. Ahora, cuando trato de usarlo en un caso muy simple no logro que me salga la respuesta con *pydoc*

test.py

```
"""Docstring del modulo."""


def hola(arg):
    """Este es el docstring de la funcion"""
    print("Hola", arg, "!")
```

Cuando escribo en el terminal:

```
$ pydoc3 test.py
```

Obtengo

```
No Python documentation found for 'test.py'.
Use help() to get the interactive help utility.
Use help(str) for help on the str class.
```

Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: entra a la consola de python , y escribes algo como `>>> import test
>>> help(test)`

Comment: Eso ya lo habia probado y funciona, lo que necesito es saber como hago para que me funcione el comando pydoc

Comment: intenta con `pydoc -w .\test.py` o incluso `python -m pydoc test`